# Please tell me, how to install pre built themes in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid

I m learning to create hybrid app using ionic, And Now and now want to use pre built themes. Please tell me how i install this.

Comment: Could you please show what you have already tried? And perhaps which themes you are trying to apply?

Comment: Did you install ionic framework ??

Answer (score 2):

You can find sample themes [here](https://market.ionic.io/themes). To install sample themes, simply add the downloaded contents to an existing Ionic project's /www folder.

However, to use a theme you must first have a working Ionic project. Generally, you can install one by typing the following into your command prompt / terminal:

```
ionic start myapp [template]
```

This will create a new project from the prebuilt template, [template] with the folder name "myapp". Some default starter templates include "tabs", "sidemenu", and "blank". For example, you can install the template "blank" with the name "coolproject" with:

```
ionic start coolproject blank
```

These are full starter projects. More full starter projects can be found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start.html). Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you've downloaded a theme from the Ionic market and have Ionic set up on your local machine.

One thing to note here is that your project MUST be an **ionic1** project.

I tried following the guide (found [here](http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/zip-export-an-ionic-project)) with an ionic2 project, but it didn't work for me. Eventually I figured out that the project needs to be ionic1.

Use `ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1` to create a ionic v1 project. Then delete the files in /www folder in your project directory, copy paste the files in your theme download (if there's a /www folder in the download then files insde it).

Now run `ionic serve`. If the app runs correctly, you're good to go. Now all you've got to do is tune the project's code as you want.